# Notation for vector space of polynomials of bounded degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, notation

Is there standard notation for the vector space of polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients in a field $F$ and with degree at most $D$?

Without bounding the degree, it is $F[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: Silverman uses $R_{d}$ where $R=F[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ in "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves", but I am not sure this is standard.

Comment: ... and with $n=1$ it would essentially  be $F[X]/(X^{D+1})$

Comment: as a variant $\mathcal P_D(F; x_1, \ldots, x_n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John McGee's comment is good.  Another way to do this is to define a set $S = \{f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) \in F[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]: \deg(f) \leq D\}$.

Or invent your own notation so long as you have clearly defined it - this happens all the time.